# installing WordNet on Mac

Tags: wordnet

I'm trying to install Wordnet 3.0 on my Mac which is OSX 10.8.

I've configured it, but when I try make,

I get a bunch of errors...

```
.....
/usr/include/tkDecls.h:1692: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘XColor’
make[2]: *** [wishwn-tkAppInit.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and then if I proceed with make install

```
Making install in doc
Making install in html
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/WordNet-3.0/doc/html" || /Users/ravenyj/Desktop/WordNet-3.0/install-sh -d "/usr/local/WordNet-3.0/doc/html"
mkdir: /usr/local/WordNet-3.0: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-htmlDATA] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I have not made any modification to Makefile, and don't know if I should.

Could anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 10):

Using brew is orders of magnitude simpler. Just:

```
brew install wordnet
```

Answer (score 9):

The following worked for me to get it to compile:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -fpermissive" CC=/usr/bin/gcc
```

then

```
make
sudo make install
```

after that it's showing up fine for me in

```
/usr/local/WordNet-3.0/
```

I then added WordNet to my $PATH by editing my .bash_profile file, adding the line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/WordNet-3.0/bin:$PATH
```

opening a new Terminal window, I could then type:

```
$ wn
```

and see that it's now working fine

Comment: dear sire, you saved my life, don't know why this answer isn't accepted after 1 year.

Comment: in order to get this working, I also had to give install-sh write access, i.e. `sudo chmod 755 install-sh`, in case someone has the same problem.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I was having a different error (X11/Xlib.h not found) but installing XQuartz (http://www.xquartz.org/) and then following this answer got it working

Answer (score 3):

Do the following to install WordNet in fastest manner:

1. Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
2. Run in Terminal app:

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
   ```

   ...and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
3. Run:

   ```
   brew install wordnet
   ```

After installation use 'wn' command in terminal to access the application.

Comment: I didn't run step one or two, just jumped straight to step three.  I received a HomeBrew error, doing so, but that error told me exactly what to do which was to run $ brew cask install xquartz.  After that I retried $brew install wordnet without issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too until I saw this webpage: http://ticanchang.blogspot.com/2010/04/install-wordnet-in-mac.html

In the folder of your downloaded WordNet package, type:

1. ./configure
2. make
3. sudo make install

You need to include "sudo" because normally a user do not have the permission to update the /usr/local folder.